# Manjaro: don't update an application

Tags: upgrade, manjaro

I've got a few local dev-servers configured on LAMP. Each time Manjaro (based on Arch) updates its software, PHP needs to be reinstalled for threading support.

I have no need to update Apache or PHP so how do I tell Linux not to update these packages?

Comment: Add the packages to the `IgnorePkg` line in `/etc/pacman.conf`. Note that partial upgrades are a bad idea on a rolling release...

Comment: oh thanks (answer my question for real so I can tick it?) Also perhaps it would be a good idea to IgnoreGroup instead? Though I wonder what group would that be..

Comment: Neither PHP nor Apache are in a group. I have added my answer, please consider that what you are proposing to do is a bad idea and will likely cause you grief when partial upgrades break your system.

Comment: i understand. You worded this especially well in the actual answer. thanks for the help. I guess if the system does break I'll come let people know here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have pacman ignore a package, you add an entry to the `IgnorePkg` array in `/etc/pacman.conf`. From the manual:

> IgnorePkg = package ...
>            Instructs pacman to ignore any upgrades for this package when performing a --sysupgrade. Shell-style glob patterns are allowed.

Note that this amounts to instructing pacman to perform a partial upgrade and should only ever be used as a temporary solution; witholding packages, particularly those that have dependencies, from upgrades will sooner or later lead to breakage in a rolling release.

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT: Jasons tip about Linux breaking is accurate. Today, 5 months later, my system does not connect to the internet. Not even by cable. Had to reinstall Manjaro. Don't know why this happened, but these two issues may indeed be connected.